# How to filter a query with one column have multiple matches in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a hard time thinking through how I can filter my query. I have a query result, and with the results I only want to show products that were ordered as an "EACH" and as a "CASE" or "INNER" for a given week.

Example output at the moment:

```
Weekno     Itemno     UnitofMeasure     ConvQty     #Orders
1           31111      EACH               1           5
1           31111      CASE               144         10
1           31112      EACH               1           10 
1           31113      CASE               144         2
2           31111      EACH               1           10
2           31112      EACH               1           20
2           31112      CASE               144         15  
2           31113      EACH               1           5
2           31113      INNER              12         20
```

So with this sample output I would only want to show as a result:

```
1           31111      EACH               1           5
1           31111      CASE               144         10
2           31112      EACH               1           20
2           31112      CASE               144         15 
2           31113      EACH               1           5
2           31113      INNER              12         20
```

Here is my current query on how I get those results:

```
SELECT datepart(ww,[Promised Ship Date]) as weekno
      ,[Item ID]
      ,[UNITOFMEASURE]
      ,[UNITOFMEASURECONV] as ConvQTY
      ,count(*) as Orders
  FROM SalesHistory vw
  inner join ITEMTABLE IT on IT.itemcode = vw.[Item Id]
  where [Promised Ship Date] >= '2016-01-01' and [Promised Ship Date] < '2016-02-01'
  and [UDF_MIN_SALES_UNIT] = 'Each'
  group by datepart(ww,[Promised Ship Date]),[item id],[unitofmeasure],[UNITOFMEASURECONV]
  order by weekno,[item id]
```

Comment: Add some "INNER" rows as well.

Comment: I understand that you exclude 31113, because it only has 'CASE'  records and no 'EACH' record. But if you select data for "a given week", how come your result contains two different weeks? And what rule makes you dismiss the two records for 31111 and 31112 your result doesn't contain?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner When it comes to picking an order from the warehouse, it is much more efficient to pick an inner or case, rather than opening up boxes to ship an EACH.  So we are trying to identify items that are currently sold as an each but also sold as an inner or case so that we can try to improve efficiency.  However we need to see what sort of measurable impact based on historical sales that the changes could have.

Comment: Ah, I see. In week 1 only item 31111 was sold both as EACH and CASE; in week 2 this was the case only for 31112.

Comment: @jarlh I added an Inner row for week 2.

Comment: `CASE, EACH, INNER` should be this order?

Comment: Wait, do you mean ("EACH" and as a "CASE") or ("INNER") OR "EACH" and as a ("CASE" or "INNER")  ?

Comment: @Ethilium: It's 'EACH' AND ('INNER' OR 'CASE') per week and item MattC is after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would count 'EACH' and 'INNER'/'CASE' per week and item and only show those week/item pairs that have a match in both.

```
select weekno, itemno, unitofmeasure, convqty, #orders
from
(
  select weekno, itemno, unitofmeasure, convqty, #orders
    , count(case when unitofmeasure = 'EACH' then 1 end) 
            over (partition by weekno, itemno) as cnt_each
    , count(case when unitofmeasure in ('INNER','CASE') then 1 end) 
            over (partition by weekno, itemno) as cnt_inner_or_case
  from mytable
) counted
where cnt_each > 0 and cnt_inner_or_case > 0;
```

Comment: Outstanding!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T TABLE(
    Weekno     INT,
    Itemno     INT,
    UnitofMeasure  VARCHAR(32),
    ConvQty     INT,
    Orders  INT)

INSERT @T
VALUES
(1, 31111, 'EACH', 1, 5),
(1, 31111, 'CASE', 144, 10),
(1, 31111, 'CASE', 144, 11),
(1, 31112, 'EACH', 1 , 10),
(1, 31113, 'CASE', 144 , 2),
(2, 31111, 'EACH', 1 , 10),
(2, 31112, 'EACH', 1 , 20),
(2, 31112, 'CASE', 144, 15), 
(2, 31113, 'CASE', 144, 5)

SELECT a.* 
FROM @T a
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT t.Weekno, t.Itemno
        FROM @T t
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT Itemno FROM @T WHERE UnitofMeasure IN ('CASE', 'INNER') AND Weekno = t.Weekno AND Itemno = t.Itemno) c
        WHERE t.UnitofMeasure = 'EACH' 
    ) q ON q.Itemno = a.Itemno AND q.Weekno = a.Weekno
```

Comment: Great answer. I would change one thing. "SELECT * " is appending q.Weekno and q.Itemno onto a's already complete results. Changing to "SELECT a.* " will provide the requested result set. Please see this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e14c9/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the following query should do the trick. It considers all UnitMeasures INNER as valid and all pairs of EACH and CASE as valid. :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Weekno int, Itemno int, UnitofMeasure varchar(10), ConvQty int, NumOrders int);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
 (1, 31111, 'EACH', 1   , 5  )
,(1, 31111, 'CASE', 144 , 10 )
,(1, 31112, 'EACH', 1   , 10 )     
,(1, 31113, 'CASE', 144 , 2  )
,(2, 31111, 'EACH', 1   , 10 )
,(2, 31112, 'EACH', 1   , 20 )
,(2, 31112, 'CASE', 144 , 15 )     
,(2, 31113, 'CASE', 144 , 5  );


WITH cte AS(
  SELECT Weekno, Itemno, UnitofMeasure, ConvQty, NumOrders, CASE WHEN UnitofMeasure IN ('CASE', 'EACH') THEN 0.5 WHEN UnitofMeasure = 'INNER' THEN 1 END AS x
    FROM @t
),
cteFilter AS(
  SELECT Weekno, Itemno, sum(x) x
     FROM cte
     GROUP BY Weekno, Itemno
     HAVING sum(x) = 1
)
SELECT t.*
  FROM @t AS t
  JOIN cteFilter AS f ON f.Weekno = t.Weekno AND f.Itemno = t.Itemno
```